# Getting indexes instead of actual values when looping through an array

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code.

```
var stuff = "mango,tango,snake";
for (thing in stuff.split(","))
  console.log(thing);
```

I was expecting three lines with the words. I'm getting three lines with indexes. I've checked the *toString* etc. methods. None helped.

1. Why?
2. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What should I use instead?*

You could use `ECMAScript 5 's` feature [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to achieve your need.

```
var stuff = "mango,tango,snake";
stuff.split(",").forEach(function(thing){ alert(thing); });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behavior. To log values, use

```
var arr = stuff.split(",");
for (var thing in arr)
  console.log(arr[thing]);
```

See [the MDN on `for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (emphasis mine) :

> A different property **name** is assigned to variable on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A *Javascript Array* is also just an *Object* and it also inherits from `Object`. But that *Array* also inherits from `Array.prototype` and gets some special methods and behaviors.

But afterall, its just an *Object*, which means its structure looks like

```
{
    0:   'mango',
    1:   'tango',
    2:   'snake'
}
```

If you loop now with `for..in` over that object, we just get the results you described (and which we should expect). The *Keys* of the object, are just the *index values* and we are just looping over the object keys, right?

To get the actual value behind a key, we access the whole object like

```
objectName[ key ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to loop through an array is to use:

```
var stuffArray=stuff.split(",");
for (var i=0, stuffLength=stuffArray.length;i<stuffLength;i++) {
    // here you can retrieve the value stuffArray[i]
}
```

There's also a [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but not supported by older browsers (like IE 8).

A for...in loop loops through the properties of the array object and might give you more than just the array items.